# Trying to copy the array or add it

Tags: java, arrays

My program is supposed to print all operations that have been done when closing in a file. The problem is that it prints everything as i wanted except the item list which is an array. So, i guess my problem is in coppying the array. here are parts of my code

```
public Item[] getItems() {
    return itemslist;
}

public void addItems(Item[] itm) {
    for (int i = 0; i < itm.length; i++)
        if (itm[i] != null) 
            itemslist[i] = itm[i];
}
```

the order gets sotored in an array when it's confirmed so that i print the array o2 in a file

```
if (jop == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    o2[orders] = new Order(o1.getId());
    o2[orders].setId(o1.getId());
    o2[orders].setTotalPrice(o1.getTotalPrice());
    o2[orders].setBarista(o1.getBarista());
    o2[orders].addItems(o1.getItems());
    orders++;
```

a try to print them which failed.

```
               outFile=new File("Orderslist.txt");
               out=new FileOutputStream(outFile);
               ob=new PrintWriter(out);

               for(int i=0;i<orders;i++){
              itms=new Item[o2[i].getItems().length];
              itms=o2[i].getItems();

                  if(o2[i]!=null){ 


                  if(o2[i].getCount()<=4){
                     ob.println(o2[i].toString()+"\n--------------\n");

                            for(int j=0;i<itms.length;j++){
                            System.out.print(itms[j].toString());}

                            ob.println("--------------\n"+"\nTotal: "+o2[i].getTotalPrice()+"\n\n\n");}

                  else if(o2[i].getCount()>4){

                             ob.println(o2[i].toString()+"\n--------------\n");

                            for(int j=0;i<itms.length;j++){
o2[i].getItems()[j].toString();}

                            ob.println("--------------\n"+"\nTotal: "+o2[i].getTotalPrice());


                            ob.println("\n\nDiscount 20%\n\n--------------\nTotal price#: "+(o2[i].getTotalPrice()-(o2[i].getTotalPrice()*0.2))+"\n\n\n");
               }
               }
            }


           ob.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean? Please tell us what output you're getting, and how that differs from what you expect. `Arrays.toString()`?

Comment: The output i got in the fail is everything i printed in it except the itms which is an array i wrote a for loop for printing it. please whats the 3rd of my code i've edited it

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; i < itms.length; j++)     
    if( itms[i]!=null)
         o2[i].getItems()[j].toString();
```

This piece does not do anything, as it just returns a String - and nothing is done with it (neither printing nor assigning to something). So you just go through the whole array and do nothing with its elements. So in case `o2[i].getCount() > 4` you will not have it printed.

Also notice, that when your first if statement is: `if (o2[i].getCount() <= 4)` then in your `else` statement you do not need to check `if (o2[i].getCount() > 4)`, because if it wouldn't be, you would not get into the else block.

Comment: So, my methods that return and add items are right, right? thanks!

Comment: Please see the third part of my code. i edited it and it still doesn't print itms array :\

Comment: I still don't see you are printing it, have you edited the code here in your question? `else if(o2[i].getCount()>4){
ob.println(o2[i].toString()+"\n--------------\n");
for(int j=0;i<itms.length;j++){o2[i].getItems()[j].toString();}` Your for loop still does nothing except iterating. You get toString() of every item, but you do not print it inside the loop, neither do you assign it anywhere. So what do you use your for loop for?